# MariaDB shows no results when I use INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

There are two tables. The IDs of Table B was created by Table A. `ID`. So, the IDs of both tables are identical.

[This is my question and real table structures.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwHmSTZMZc0oa2VnRE1lNUoyQzQ?usp=sharing)

I have tried to merge two tables into one table, but the query shows no result.

This is my query.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.type, B.ID, B.result 
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

I don't know what I did wrong. I thought it is quite simple JOIN syntax. 
Can you explain what I did wrong?

Comment: If your are getting no results, then no ids match between the two tables. Or (really a subset of that condition), one or both tables are empty.

Comment: Thanks.. but Table A has 283 records, and B has 44500 records.. And both IDs are same. I don't know why this is not working...

Comment: Please show the table structure (`describe A;' and 'describe B;'), so we can verify the column names in your query.

Comment: Either 1) IDs don't match between 2 tables. OR 2) One ID is `char` and another is `varchar`

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question :) @Pdc

Comment: @Utsav  thanks. I checked that problems. but both key property are same (varchar 15) and I could print what i want using manual query, like key = 'bla bla bla'.  Also I tested trim() function to get rid of empty spaces.. but it won't work. :(

Comment: Use post.it or some other service to show us the schema and a few of the rows of each table.

Comment: You are joining on `admno`?

Comment: @RickJames thank you for your concern. Finally I solved this problem. there's an invisible byte difference in on column. I don't know this byte what is. But anyway, it works! :)

Comment: If you can get the `HEX()` of the string, I can probably figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear titans of the stack overflow.

I've solved this problem. 
I had tried to join the two tables using **admno** column. 
It looked same, and the data types are same. but After checking the length of that data, I found out that there is something, an invisible byte in one column.
(The trim() function was not able to remove that byte)

I used char_length() function at each key column. It revealed that one is 14, and another is 15. 
I don't know what is the invisible. But it worked!

Thank you all!